# How to make a button on/off switch?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using VS2013, C#, .Net  and Winforms how can I make a regular Button look "pressed"? Imagine this button is an on/off switch. ToolStripButton has the Checked property, but the regular Button does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the files are available to your site, activating the script is very easy:

...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(':checkbox').iphoneStyle();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a custom requirement i.e. the button you need does not exist in the regular controls, I suggest you create a custom control button for your needs. Here is a link of a tutorial to create a custom control : [How to: Create a Custom Image Button Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms172532%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can also use a third party control like : [Telerik Button - Radios and Checkboxes](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/radiosandcheckboxes/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Are you really forced to use a button or does it just have to look like one? For the latter you can just use a checkbox with the `Appearance`  set to `Button` and `Checked=true`. This will make the checkbox appear like a button which is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can change button's background image or background color in button click event handler.
Decalre somewhere in your code :

```
bool isClicked = false;
```

In event handler you can do :

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    btn.BackgroundImage = isClicked? image1 : image2; // or use BackColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and elegant solution. You can take a look how .NET draws it itself and try to do the same.
You should basically use

```
System.Windows.Forms.ButtonRenderer
```

class for drawing buttons in different states (Pressed, Hover etc.)
Please try to avoid using images for displaying states because to do it correctly, you would need to support different DPIs, sizing, proportions and so on. Rely on standard Render* classes fist.